# Error #1088 on passing a class as a parameter for web service in Flash Builder

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

I need to pass a struct and a string in a web service. I am using a WebService components to do so.

upon my search, there is no struct type in actionscript and so I used a class for that one.

```
public class UserInfo{
  public var name:String;
  public var dateAdded:Date;
}
```

and I'm filling it up so that I can pass it on the web service like this:

```
var newUser:UserInfo = new UserInfo();
newUser.name = "myName";
newUser.birthdate = new Date();


webServComponentId.operationToCall(newUser, "password");
```

Upon sending this request, it prompts me an error of Error #1088. It seems that the error is an XML related issue telling that it is malformed. Any ideas on how to solve this? or what the problem is?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Sorry for the lack of the other details:

the component that is being called by webServComponentId.operationToCall(newUser, "password"); is this:

```
<s:WebService id="webServComponent" wsdl="[PATH OF WSDL HERE]" >
  <s:operation name="operationToCall" result="functionToCallWhenResult(event);" fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString)" />
</s:WebService>
```

Basically it is a web service via MXML. So when I call the operation, it always go to fault part and shows Error #1088

Comment: Maybe it's just me but I have failed to locate the operationToCall() method in WebService component so please elaborate. Btw, check this: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/soap/mxml/Operation.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems that I am passing the wrong data in here.. the parameter to be used inside the class needs to be the same as the parameter used on the struct on the server. So as to speak in code,

```
<xmlTag>
   <birthdate>010588</birthdate>
</xmlTag>
```

is different from

```
<xmlTag>
   <bdate>010588</bdate>
</xmlTag>
```